# ERROR CURL The curl request does not pass

Tags: php, curl

Where is the mistake?
The curl request does not pass.
I'm trying to pass a POST request that occurs when a particular button is clicked on the site.
The message I receive when I open the php script (index.php) locally.
On the site to which I send an action request does not occur

```
curl_setopt( $myCurl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.opskins.com/ICart/AddToCart/v1/' );
curl_setopt( $myCurl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array (
 'origin: https://opskins.com', 
 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br', 
 'accept-language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7', 
 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36', 
 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', 
 'accept: */*', 
 'referer: https://opskins.com/?loc=shop_browse&app=730_2', 
 'authority: api.opskins.com', 
 'cookie: bla=bla; many_many=bukaff', 
  ));
curl_setopt($myCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($myCurl, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, '8000');
curl_setopt($myCurl, CURLOPT_PROXY, '1.1.1.1'); 
curl_setopt($myCurl, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, 'xxxx:xxxxxxxx');
curl_setopt( $myCurl, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt($myCurl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
'saleid'=>'181679504',
'location'=>'shop_browse',
'amount'=>'192',
'internal_search'=>'',
'csrf'=>'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
));
curl_setopt ($cn, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);        

$response = curl_exec($myCurl);
echo $response;
   echo 'error curl: ' . curl_error($myCurl);
curl_close($myCurl);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);`
to correct on it
`curl_setopt ($myCurl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);`